# adding a border to a UIButton with auto-layout

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, autolayout

I have a custom `UIView`. In its `init` method I add a button and would like to add a top red border. I am trying to also do this with auto-layout but when running the console tells me that it can not satisfy all the constraints. What am I overlooking?

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        _button = [[UIButton alloc] init];

        UIView *border = [[UIView alloc] init];
        border.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [_button addSubview:border];

        [_button addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[border]|"
                                                                        options:0 metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(border)]];
        [_button addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[border(1)]"
                                                                        options:0 metrics:0 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(border)]];
        [self addSubview:_button];

        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_button(35)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_button)]];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_button(35)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_button)]];

    }
    return self;
}
```

This is the console message:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79f73ce0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x79f72ec0]   (Names: '|':UIButton:0x79f72900 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79f73d10 H:[UIView:0x79f72ec0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIButton:0x79f72900 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79f73b40 H:[UIButton:0x79f72900(35)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x79f327c0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x79f72ec0.midX ==>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79f73d10 H:[UIView:0x79f72ec0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIButton:0x79f72900 )>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x79f327c0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x79f72ec0.midX ==>"
```

indicates that an autoresizing mask was implicitly added to the `border`, which was translated into a conflicting auto layout constraint.

Setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` should solve the issue:

```
UIView *border = [[UIView alloc] init];
border.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO
```